# How to deselect an entire QTableWidget row

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Given the row index, how can I deselect a single row in a QTableWidget? I don't want to deselect everything using clearSelection()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table [`selectionModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html) and its [`select()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#select) function, using the `Deselect` and `Rows` flags:

```
    def deselectRow(self, row):
        if row > self.table.rowCount() - 1:
            return
        selectionModel = self.table.selectionModel()
        selectionModel.select(self.table.model().index(row, 0), 
            selectionModel.Deselect|selectionModel.Rows)
```